# How does this create a proc object?

Tags: ruby

```
def makeProc(&obj)
  obj
end

puts makeProc{|x,y| x+y}.class
```

How does obj become a Proc type when a block is passed to it as reference? Is there any reason or it is like some kind of ruby magic?

Answer (score 1):

The `&` ampersand unary prefix sigil in a parameter list denotes a so-called "block parameter". It basically means something like "wrap the block argument in a proper `Proc` object and bind it to this parameter name".

Remember: blocks are supposed to be syntactically and semantically lightweight, and one way in which they achieve this, is that they aren't objects and can't be named. The result of this is that you can only do three things with blocks:

1. ignore them
2. `yield` to them
3. check if a block was passed (using `block_given?`)

That's it. If you want to do anything beyond that, you need a) an object and b) a name, which is what the `&` ampersand unary prefix sigil does.

In an *argument* list, the `&` ampersand unary prefix operator does the inverse: it unwraps a `Proc` object into a block (or, if the object is not a `Proc` already, it sends it the `to_proc` message to convert it into a `Proc`).

Comment: yeah I just did a hard check and you're of course correct, `Proc.new` is never called. I should have done this before posting. The textbook (a well-known one) from which I gleaned this theory, clearly alludes to `Proc.new` being called during this process, so I made a genuine mistake.